Scrape comments from dynamically changing site
I need to scrape/parse comments from Debank site's posts.
For example: https://debank.com/stream/2057406
The problem is that if I scroll the site the html changes and rendering comments in real time.
Every comment has it's id, and when I scroll the site the new comments adds and the previous one disappears.
Dynamic code
For example first comment has attribute data-index="0", second has data-index="1" and it works like this:
Page loaded
A little scroll to look at the comment section
We see comments and in f12 mode their ID's
data-index="0" data-index="1" data-index="2" data-index="3"
We scroll more
data-index="1" data-index="2" data-index="3" data-index="4"
We scroll more
data-index="2" data-index="3" data-index="4" data-index="5"
And so on..
I tried using requests, selenium and even downloading source code and trying parsing it on my computer, but all I get is a first few comments, but I need them all.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You can try using their rest API (probably you need to adjust the HTTP x-api-* headers too):
import requests

id_ = 2057406
comments_url = "https://api.debank.com/article/comments?id={id}&start={start}&limit=20&order_by=-trust_degree"

headers = {
    "x-api-nonce": "n_XaAx0SDDZtZFMoTbw7KXX8PTERJWl5pFFGcCs6lb",
    "x-api-sign": "6e9ceb1c9431a2d47cf549a3910e3df91eb6b64b58453b2c6e6906c659f34f05",
    "x-api-ts": "1715028741",
    "x-api-ver": "v2",
}

data = requests.get(comments_url.format(id=id_, start=0), headers=headers).json()
for c in data["data"]["comments"]:
    print(c["content"])
    print()

Prints:
I always follow back on "Hi Message"

Hopefully a real tokens airdrop and not another points system

Same here I unfollowed a bunch of addresses and the more surprising was that some sent me a hi to be followed and still unfollowed me :D

I must be annoying them a lot with my posts 

If there are points like on Rabby, it depends on whether they admit it once or whether it will be open to further collection. And if so, what will they continue to award them for and how long will it last? I would prefer if they counted once and closed the Airdrop collection.

really hope they won't announce a point system after a year farming it 

unfollow

Do you trust airdrop ? I feel like 2024 airdrop are just bad



...


import re
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def save_comment_to_file(comment):
    with open('comments.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        if comment in file.read():
            print("Comment is already exists:", comment)
        else:
            file.write(comment + '\n')
            print("Comment is saved:", comment)

def check_hex_string(s):
    if len(s) == 34 and s[:2] == "0x":
        return True
    else:
        return False

options = Options()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://debank.com/stream/2054429')
def scrapeComments():
 
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    folded_comments_clicked = False
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)  
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        
        log_entries = driver.get_log('performance')
        for entry in log_entries:
            try:
                obj_serialized: str = entry.get('message')
                obj = json.loads(obj_serialized)
                message = obj.get('message')
                method = message.get('method')
                params = message.get('params')
                if method == 'Network.loadingFinished':
                    requestId = params.get('requestId')
                    body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': requestId})
                    if "comments" in str(body):
                        pattern = r'"content":"(.*?)"'
                        contents = re.findall(pattern, str(body))
                        if len(contents) > 0:
                            for comment in contents:
                                if check_hex_string(comment):
                                    save_comment_to_file(comment)
                            
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:", e)
                
        folded_comments_header = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'FoldedComments_header__A1ory')
        if folded_comments_header and not folded_comments_clicked:
            folded_comments_header[0].click()
            folded_comments_clicked = True

driver.quit()


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In Selenium, you can do
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", item)

to cause the browser to scroll item into view, and (hopefully) cause the site code to load the next item (if it isn't loaded already). You can use this to work your way down the sequence of items, beyond the few that are initially loaded.
